# xrandr and nvidia card not working; display unclaimed (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, xrandr, nvidia-optimus

I have a new HP Envy laptop with two graphic cards

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 "\[03..\]:" 
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Intel Tigerlake UHD Graphics
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [103c:8815]
    Kernel modules: i915
--
0000:01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] [10de:1f95] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] [103c:8815]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
0000:2c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
```

Unfortunately, the cards seem not to work properly. If i use my NVIDIA with `prime-select nvidia` and restart, it boots into a black screen and i have to use `tty` to rune `prime-select intel` and reboot to get the login screen back.

Furthermore, not only the NVIDIA card seems to have problems, the Intel as well since `xrandr` does not work

```
$ xrandr --prop 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 1920 x 1200
default connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   1920x1200     77.00*
```

I noticed this problem since `redshift` does not work (due to `xrandr` failing). Additionally i can not adjust the display brightness (which could also be a result of `xrandr`?).

I also noticed, that `lshw` states that the display is unclaimed

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:601e000000-601effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:61000000-61ffffff memory:6020000000-602fffffff memory:6030000000-6031ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Has someone an idea how to get my cards to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=nomodeset` in the grub file set. That prevented that the Intel driver was loaded. Hence, removing `nomodeset` seolved the problem.